# Install for all users doesn't give access to external community users

Tags: visualforce, community, managed-package, access

My managed package includes a visualforce page which is added to Account layout. When the package is installed with "Install for All Users" setting, it works even if a specific user profile doesn't have access to this visualforce page explicitly.

However, I noticed that external users(In a community) get Insufficient Access error. If admin makes the vf page available to external user's profile explicitly, it works.

Is this the intended behaviour, that is, are external users treated different than internal ones w.r.t to the setting "Install for All Users" for a managed package?

Is there a way I can control it through managaed package so the admins don't need to give access to external users explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats perfectly expected behavior and is documented in the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.appExchangeInstallGuide.meta/appExchangeInstallGuide/appexchange_install_installation.htm)

[image]

Create a permission set with Visualforce access and the administrator can assign the permission set to the Community Users .